# Cloud Firestore is not triggering onWrite in wildcard

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am trying write an aggragation function to update a few details on a value change of a nested object of a doc in wildcard.

```
exports.createAccessDetails = functions.firestore.document('classrooms/{classId}/access/{accessType}').onWrite((snap, context) => {
  // const data = snap.data();
  const { classId, accessType } = context.params;
  console.log(snap);
  console.log(classId, accessType);
  return null;
});
```

Then updating the object like on a button click

```
function setAccess() {
  const date = Date.now();
  Firebase.firestore.collection('classrooms')
    .doc('1570776211111').update({
      [`access.writeAccess.${date}`]: true
    });
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Why the function didnt trigger?

Comment: Can you give more details on what you are exactly trying to achieve. As pepe explained in his answer, you update to `collection('classrooms').doc('1570776211111')` but your Cloud Function is defined to be triggered when you write to `collection('classrooms').doc('1570776211111').collection('access').doc('xyz')`. So were do you exactly want to update? in collection `classrooms` or in the `access` sub-collection of a classroom?

Comment: So, `classrooms` has a huge object where I'm updating a key `access` which has another key called `writeAccess` or another type, with different data.
Currently, I didn't create `access` as a different collection, I'm pushing it as an object of the collection `classrooms`. Now from Pepe's comment I understand if I have to listen for a change in the object of `access/{accessType}` I have to make`access` a subclass of `classrooms`, is that correct? If so, I have to rewrite my query too? Currently querying based on `firestore.collection('classrooms').where(`access.readAccess.${id}`, '==', true)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comment above, it appears that you want to write (update) a document of the `classrooms` collection. More precisely, update the `access` field which is of type Map (see [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types) for Firestore types).

So your Cloud Function shall simply be triggered when you update this document and to get the value of the `access` map you will call `snap.data().access`.

```
exports.createAccessDetails = functions.firestore.document('classrooms/{classId}').onWrite((snap, context) => {
  const data = snap.data();

  const accessMap = snap.data().access;
  const writeAccessMap = accessMap.writeAccess

  //........

  return null;
});
```

---

**Update following your comment below:**

I don't have a full view of your exact business requirements (in particular I see that you mention writeAccess and readAccess) but you could maybe have the following approach:

For each `classroom` doc you create two sub-collections: `writeAccess` and `readAccess`. Each time you want to save an access you write a new document in one of these collections.

You can then query the sub-collections to find the docs where a given id has read or write access. Then from the QueryDocumentSnapshot returned by these queries you can find the parent document (through the `ref` property).

However, this means that you will have an extra read to get the classroom details from the results of the queries to the `writeAccess` and `readAccess` collections.

Comment: Well yes, I could do that. I was mostly wanted to listen to only to update the access field. The reason for me not doing that was not to trigger this function every time I change something in `{classId}`. If I change any other id in the doc, it will triger the function. So I think it's wise to create a sub-collection of `access` and listen to the changes in the `access` sub-collection docs. Which reminds me, will that count as one more doc read count right? Also the last question, I might need to rewrite the query to get my `claasrooms` data.

Comment: @SubhenduKundu is this still an issue for you?

Answer (score 0):

The update operation will not trigger the cloud function.Because you wrote the trigger function for a sub collection named access and you are making an upadation on a root collection called classroom.So the above written trigger function will trigger only for sub collection called access not for the root collection called classroom.Hope this will help you

Comment: Is there any way I can achieve this? Listen for changes in a sub-collection named access?

Comment: The same function you have written will trigger if there is any change in sub collection called access